# Error compiling project that uses libvncserver

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to compile a project that uses libvncserver.

This is my Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = rcmain.o events.o util.o cursor.o sockets.o table_crypt.o
LOBJ = launcher.o util.o d3des/d3des.o
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -static-libgcc -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu99
LIBS = -lXtst -lXext -lX11 -lpthread -ljpeg -lz

all: $(OBJS) $(LOBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a -o tvnc
    strip -s tvnc

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.bak core ivvnc tvnc
```

I'm getting the fallowing error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(rfbserver.o): na função `rfbClientConnectionGone':
(.text+0x934): referência indefinida para `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(rfbserver.o): na função `rfbClientConnectionGone':
(.text+0x948): referência indefinida para `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(rfbserver.o): na função `rfbSendFileTransferChunk':
(.text+0x1d5e): referência indefinida para `compress'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(rfbserver.o): na função `rfbProcessFileTransfer':
(.text+0x237a): referência indefinida para `uncompress'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(websockets.o): na função `webSocketsEncodeHixie':
(.text+0x26): referência indefinida para `__b64_ntop'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(websockets.o): na função `webSocketsEncodeHybi':
(.text+0xd4): referência indefinida para `__b64_ntop'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(websockets.o): na função `webSocketsDecodeHybi':
(.text+0x4bc): referência indefinida para `__b64_pton'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(websockets.o): na função `webSocketsDecodeHixie':
(.text+0x774): referência indefinida para `__b64_pton'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a(websockets.o): na função `webSocketsCheck':
(.text+0xfb6): referência indefinida para `__b64_ntop
...
```

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to add a link-flag for libvncserver? (`-lvncserver`)?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons He is already static linking it explicitly - `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvncserver.a` - and the undefined references are *in* it, not *to* it.

Comment: Using the link flag -lvncserver, is there any way to include statically this lib in my application? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're linking to zlib too early; order matters when it comes to linking to static libraries. Try putting `$(LIBS)` *after* the vncserver static library.

You may want to consider using `pkg-config`; libvncserver ships a *.pc file, and this is pretty much what it was designed for… on my system, `pkg-config --libs libvncserver` looks like:

```
-lvncserver -lnsl -lpthread -lz -lpng -ljpeg -lresolv -lgcrypt -ldl -lgpg-error -lgnutls -lz
```

Comment: He is linking `-lz`, but too early

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly! Can I take advantage and ask another question? Do you know how I could adapt this makefile to compile for both 32 and 64 bits?

Comment: @Guilherme Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
If you have another question, hit [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)